# How to do an efficient, nonrecursive topological sort on an immutable graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Is there a good way to do an efficient, nonrecursive topological sort on an immutable graph?  I've a situation where I'm traversing a graph linked together by pointers and I need to do a topological sort.  It's important to me not to modify the graph, but I'm not sure how to mark a node as visited and check it efficiently without doing so.  At the moment, I have a set to store the markings, but I know the search occurs in `log(m)` time.  Is there a way to do this better?  Here's some working code:

```
// For std::shared_ptr
#include <memory>

// For std::list, std::stack, std::set
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <set>

// For std::cout
#include <iostream>

// Node in a directed acyclic graph with only two exiting edges
struct Node {
    // Identity of the node for debugging
    char identity;

    // Left and right branches
    std::shared_ptr <Node> left;
    std::shared_ptr <Node> right;

    // Create a node
    Node(
        char const & identity_,
        std::shared_ptr <Node> const & left_,
        std::shared_ptr <Node> const & right_
    ) : identity(identity_), left(left_), right(right_)
    {}
};


// Determines a topological sort of a directed acyclic graph of compute nodes
std::list <std::shared_ptr <Node>> topo_sort(
    std::shared_ptr <Node> const & root
) {
    // Add the root node to the todo list.  The todo list consists of
    // (ptr,whether we've searched left,whether we've searched right).
    auto todo = std::stack <std::tuple <std::shared_ptr <Node>,bool,bool>> ();
    todo.push(std::make_tuple(root,false,false));

    // Add an empty list for the sorted elements
    auto sorted = std::list <std::shared_ptr <Node>> {};

    // Keep track of which nodes have been marked
    auto marked = std::set <std::shared_ptr <Node>> {root};

    // Determines if a node has been marked
    auto is_marked = [&](auto const & node) {
        return marked.find(node)!=marked.end();
    };

    // Loop over the elements in the todo stack until we have none left to
    // process
    while(todo.size()>0) {
        // Grab the current node
        auto & current = todo.top(); 
        auto & node = std::get <0> (current);
        auto & searched_left = std::get <1> (current);
        auto & searched_right = std::get <2> (current);

        // Grab the left and right nodes
        auto left = node->left;
        auto right = node->right;

        // Do a quick check to determine whether we actually have children
        if(!left)
            searched_left = true;
        if(!right)
            searched_right = true;

        // If we've already transversed both left and right, add the node to
        // the sorted list
        if(searched_left && searched_right) {
            sorted.push_front(node);
            marked.insert(node);
            todo.pop();

        // Otherwise, traverse the left branch if that node hasn't been marked
        } else if(!searched_left) {
            searched_left = true;
            if(!is_marked(left)) {
                todo.push(std::make_tuple(left,false,false));
                marked.insert(left);
            }

        // Next, traverse the right branch if that node hasn't been marked
        } else if(!searched_right) {
            searched_right = true;
            if(!is_marked(right)) {
                todo.push(std::make_tuple(right,false,false));
                marked.insert(right);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the topological sort
    return sorted;
}

int main() {
    // Create a graph with some dependencies
    auto a = std::make_shared <Node> ('a',nullptr,nullptr);
    auto b = std::make_shared <Node> ('b',nullptr,nullptr);
    auto c = std::make_shared <Node> ('c',a,a);
    auto d = std::make_shared <Node> ('d',b,c);
    auto e = std::make_shared <Node> ('e',d,c);
    auto f = std::make_shared <Node> ('f',e,c);

    // Sort the elements
    auto sorted = topo_sort(f);

    // Print out the sorted order
    for(auto const & node : sorted)
        std::cout << node->identity << std::endl;
}
```

which gives

```
f
e
d
c
a
b
```

The above should do a depth first search for the sort.  And, yes, I realize this is a funny looking tree for a graph, but the left and right elements don't have to point at unique elements.  In any case, thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> std::unorderd_set Solution

Instead of `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Node>>`, you can use `std::unordered_set<Node*>` to mark the visited nodes. `unordered_set` use hash to index nodes (complexity: constant on average), and it should be faster than `set` in most cases. Also save the raw pointer, i.e. `Node*`, in container, is faster than `shared_ptr`, since there's no reference count operations.

If this solution takes too much memory, you can try the `bitmap` solution.

> bitmap Solution

Give each node an id beginning from 0, and use a `bitmap` to save the visited status.

Initialize the `bitmap` with all bits setting to 0. When visiting the *nth* node (whose id is `n`), set the *nth* bit on the `bitmap`. When you want to find out if a given node has been visited, you just check whether the corresponding bit has been set.

This solution only takes `n` bits of memory, where `n` is the number of nodes in your tree.

Comment: I'm expected a pretty huge number of nodes, which is a large reason why I'm not doing this iteratively since it will cause a stack overflow.  Would `std::unordered_set` still be the correct choice in that situation?

Comment: `std::unordered_set` allocates memory on heap, NOT on stack. So it won't  cause a stack overflow.

Comment: For sure, but is there a risk that the computational complexity will be bad if there's a large number of nodes.  It's hard for me to tell how many there are, but probably millions to billions.in some cases.

Comment: I update the answer with a `bitmap` solution, which takes only `n` bits of memory. However, you have to add a new data member, i.e. `id`, for the `Node` class.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer.  In general, I would agree that the `bitmap` solution would work well, but this is an odd case where I really am pointer chasing and it's not fully clear to me how many nodes there are in the graph.  It corresponds to a computation.  If the computation is short, there's not many nodes.  If it's long, there's a lot of nodes.  Even if I count the overall number of nodes with a global variable, I may need to sort a graph that corresponds to a subcomputation and it's not clear how many nodes are in that subgraph.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I could count the number of edges in the graph below a particular node.  Not every edge goes to a unique node, but it would provide an upper bound on the number of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithmic complexity is almost always fast enough. std::map and std::set also have another advantage over hash tables - the performance is guaranteed 100% of the time, a property very useful in e.g. hard real-time systems. A hash table is faster than a red-black tree (map,set) most of the time, but e.g. if a rehash is necessary, worst-case performance will hit you.